# Work with characters in R

Tags: r

Sorry for disturbing with this scrap, but I have no idea what's wrong...

My data frame seems like below:

```
DF <- data.frame(user = c(1,2,3,4,5), sentence1 = c("hl",NA,"hel","helllo",NA),sentence2 = c("hi",NA,"cheers",NA, NA))
```

And I have a function, which removes rows in DF if nchar in sentence1 is less than 3...

Function is:

```
TooLong <- function(sentences) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(sentences)) {
    if (nchar(as.character(sentences[i,2])) < 3) {sentences[i,] <-   sentences[i,]}
    else {sentences[-i,]}
  }
  sentences
}
```

And call:

```
DF <- TooLong(DF)
```

I don't know, where is a mistake and function doesn't work... Please, could you anyone help me and if so, is there faster or better approach for that. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean to you? What is the output you expect for your desired input. Describe in words what you expect your function to do.

Comment: Yeah, to me. I'm expecting the function removes row where nchar(DF$sentence1 ) < 3. So DF without 1.,2. and 5 row :-)

Comment: `DF[grepl('^.{3,}$', DF$sentence1),]`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution in my opinion

`subset(DF, nchar(as.character(sentence1)) > 3)`

Comment: I think you would want to have it as `>=3` to retain the correct data.

Comment: Perfect, it works fine :-), thank you very much...

And do you happen to know, what is wrong in my approach? I mean in my function.

Comment: It's hideous in every way, and the worst possible way to handle data in R.  Check out http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#page=18

Comment: In terms of why it fails, you're assignment is wrong.  This would work `TooLong <- function(sentences) {for (i in 1:nrow(sentences)) if (nchar(as.character(sentences[i,2])) < 3) sentences <- sentences[-i,]; sentences}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely with subsetting:

```
DF[nchar(as.character(DF$sentence1))>=3,]
  user sentence1 sentence2
3    3       hel    cheers
4    4    helllo      <NA>
```

The error in your function is that it does not do a replacement in the else clause. Even if it did, because it is trying to modify the data in-place, it think the indices would get messed up. A while loop would be better.

Comment: But if I split all the parts of that function and try e.g. DF[-2,] when condition is FALSE it should work... but it doesn't. I'm only curious, how that function should looks like to be working correctly...

Comment: You would need it to be something like `{sentences <- sentences[-i]; i <- i-1}`. The `i` value being decremented because you have removed a row. But as I said a `for` loop wouldn't work with this kind of construct.

Comment: Actually, you could do it with a for loop if you worked in reverse since this would avoid the reordering of data problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr); DF %>% filter(!nchar(as.character(sentence1)) < 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DF[,2:3]<-lapply(DF[,2:3],as.character) #convert sentence 1 and sentence 3 into character
DF[nchar(DF[,2])>=nchar(DF[,3]),]
  user sentence1 sentence2
1    1        hl        hi
2    2      <NA>      <NA>
4    4    helllo      <NA>
5    5      <NA>      <NA>
```